# Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I am trying to add Role-based Authentication to my **Delete User API.** My implementation is-
**SecurityConfigs.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigs {
    

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailService;
....
}
```

**UserController.java: Delete method**

```
 @DeleteMapping("/{userid}")
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") //NOW ONLY THE USERS WITH ADMIN ROLES WILL BE PERMITTED
        public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> deleteUser(@PathVariable("userid") Integer uid){
            
            // ResponseEntity<?> deletedUser=
            this.userService.deleteUser(uid);
            return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(new ApiResponse("user deleted successfully",true),HttpStatus.OK);

        }
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter.java class**

```
@Component // to enable autowiring
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = JwtAuthenticationFilter.class.getName();
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;

    /*
     * This method will be called everytime the APIs are
     * hit by the user
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get token
        // key is "Authorization" -get its value
        String requestToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        // token starts from Bearer <token value>
        System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Token in request: " + requestToken);
        // fetch the username
        String username = null;

        String token = null;

        if (requestToken != null && requestToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {

            // we found token
            token = requestToken.substring(7);// Bearer 44894732e8732
            System.out.println("Token obtained as: " + token);
            try {
                username = this.jwtTokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);
                System.out.println("Username obtained as: " + username);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Unable to get JWT Token: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Jwt Token has expried: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Malformed Jwt token: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Jwt token does not begin with \"Bearer\" ");
        }

        // once we get the token, now validate
        if (
        // username should not be null
        username != null &&
        // also, Spring security should not be authenticating any user
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (this.jwtTokenHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                // this means the token is valid
                // create an authentication instance
                System.out.println(username + " Granted authorities for the user: " + userDetails.getAuthorities());
                // userDetails.getAuthorities() gives the list of all the granted authorities
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                // set the details
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // now authentication using SecurityContextHolder
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                System.out.println("Authentication is set for " + username);

            } else {
                System.out.println(CLASS_NAME + " Invalid jwt token");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    CLASS_NAME + " Username is null: " + username + " or authentication context is not null");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Returning from doFilterInternal() for: " + username);
    }
}
```

**Problem-**
When I run my application and authenticate the user with **ADMIN role**, I get the token in the correct manner. But when I try to use the **Delete API** using the ADMIN role, I get the **Status Code 403 Forbidden error**, although I am permitting the **ADMIN** role to perform this operation.
I get the following logs-

```
com.ayushsingh.bloggingapplication.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter Token in request: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJheXVzaHNpbmdoQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTY2NjAwNDQyMywiaWF0IjoxNjY2MDAzMzQzfQ.8eMmOBNSLyOGYgxWHL8k-bet39VO_UqZKunN7MfxlPo08xFzu0-5i1-9dKMkI1871shkTz0U1drLM9tAAHzU5g
Token obtained as: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJheXVzaHNpbmdoQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTY2NjAwNDQyMywiaWF0IjoxNjY2MDAzMzQzfQ.8eMmOBNSLyOGYgxWHL8k-bet39VO_api/users/11
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : **Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity** com.ayushsingh.bloggingapplication.controllers.UserController.deleteUser(java.lang.Integer); target is of class [com.ayushsingh.bloggingapplication.controllers.UserController] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasRole('ADMIN')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : **Responding with 403 status codeReturning from doFilterInternal() for: ayushsingh@gmail.com**
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request      
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing DELETE /error
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext     
2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext 2022-10-17 16:15:34.577 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        
: Secured DELETE /error2022-10-17 16:15:34.587 DEBUG 22596 --- [nio-8085-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete
```

The response of the API call is-
[image]
I am not able to find the cause of this problem. Please help!

Comment: Please format log output as code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

if your relation is one to many do not return null in getAuthorities :

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Role> roles =new ArrayList<>();
     roles.add(role);
     List<GrantedAuthority> gauth=roles.stream().map((rol)->new 
     SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
     return gauth;
}
```

if your relation is many to many :

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<GrantedAuthority> gauth=role.stream().map((rol)-> new 
    SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return gauth;
```